# Git clone: remove warning "you appear to have cloned an empty repository"

Tags: linux, bash, git, command-line-interface, git-clone

I want to remove the warning when I clone an empty repository with `git clone`.

Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941594/git-clone-how-do-i-supress-the-you-appear-to-have-cloned-an-empty-repository), I want a solution that works for all languages. My computer is in French, and the message is `warning: Vous semblez avoir cloné un dépôt vide.` and some of my co-workers have their computer in english.

Is there a more elegant solution to my problem?

Comment: Append `2>/dev/null` to the `git clone` command. But it silences the progress too.

Comment: and it silences the error messages, too. I don't want this behavior.

Comment: How frequently do you clone empty repositories such that the warning becomes a problem, I have to wonder? If it really bothers you, you can compile your own version of Git that does not warn you in this case.

Comment: It gives you the warning because there is never a reason to do this. If you want an empty repo, create one.

Comment: @stark I wouldn't say *never a reason*, because if you clone an empty repo, that also configures the remote location. If you initialize a repo from scratch, you would have set up the remote location manually. But... there is no reason to clone an empty repo dozens of times.

Comment: My project repos are auto-generated. So every week, I have to clone an empty repository - or git init and add remote. I wanted a simple way of initialise on of these repository without theses waring, by using clone. @j6t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no configuration variable or command line option to turn off this warning (see [the code in `clone.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/clone.c#L1277)).

---

The options I see are :

- disable all of stderr,
- spot the translation of that message and grep it out,
- write an alias for `git init && git remote add origin <url>`

Comment: I'll stick using `init && remote`, thank you